# Understanding the Sub-expression overflow reasoning

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I am trying to understand the reasoning behind this particular suggestion in Visual Studio 2022, as it doesn't seem to make sense to me.  Here's the simple code:

```
static constexpr uint32_t MAX_ELEMENTS = 100000;
const std::vector<int> A{ some random ints };


std::vector<bool> found(MAX_ELEMENTS);
for (int value : A)
{
    if (value > 0 && value <= MAX_ELEMENTS)
        found[value - 1] = true;             // Problem it complains about is the value - 1.
}
```

It suggests that a *"sub-expression may overflow before being added to a wider type"*. Now obviously the condition-if prevents this from ever happening, but what's the reasoning here?

Now if this was a Spectre thing, I could understand that the compiler would add a memory fence to stop any speculative execution of the statement after the if, but I don't think that's the answer here.

My only thinking is that it has to do with the subscript operator on the vector; that its index is of a type larger than int and is implicitly cast to size_t?

Just seems a little unintuitive that the below is an issue:

```
found[value - 1]
```

and its perfectly fine to do this,

```
int a = value - 1;
found[a];
```

when the end result is the same.  What am I missing here in terms of understanding?

Comment: @Sebastian: Only signed overflow is UB, unsigned overflow is modular as per the spec.

Comment: Deleted wrong comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it is a false positive, as you suspected. This is a rule that sometimes gets used in stricter code bases. (This particular warning is an error in MISRA, for example.)

A lot of warnings are like this... the compiler writers are *trying* to detect a situation where the behavior of the program is unexpected or unintentional, but the warnings are not always correct. For example,

```
uint64_t x = 0xffffffffu << 16;
```

On a system with 32-bit int, the standard is *very clear* what the value of this is supposed to be... it's supposed to be:

```
uint64_t x = 0xffff0000u;
```

However, it does *look* like someone meant to write this instead:

```
uint64_t x = (uint64_t)0xffff0000 << 16;
```

That's what the warning is trying to catch. That's the *reasoning* behind this rule. In your case, the compiler is doing a bad job of it.

You can see a more detailed justification for the warning in the compiler documentation: [Warning C26451](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26451).

Spectre has nothing to do with it.

### It's perfectly fine...

To do this:

```
int a = value - 1;
found[a];
```

In this case the "intent" is more obvious, because the programmer has explicitly written out "int" as the type.

### Solutions

This is a code style issue, so there are a few different solutions and you pick whatever one you feel comfortable with.

- Leave the warning on (noisy, may distract you from real warnings)
- Assign the expression to an int first (verbose)
- Disable the warning across the code base (if you don't think it's helpful)
- Disable the warning around this location with a [`#pragma warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170) (very verbose)

Comment: Other (often better) solutions for fixing warnings could be: Fix the reason for the warning or rewrite the overall code in a way the compiler does not issue a warning.

Comment: @Sebastian Whilst I agree with you completely here, the above code is simple enough to understand without rewriting it to get around a warning where there shouldn't be one.